# Как подключиться к другому компьютеру в глобальной сети?

Tags: c++, c, winsock

Пишу приложение по сетям. На одном компьютере все работает, на разных компьютерах в одной локальной сети тоже все работает, но на разных компьютерах в разных сетях не получается получить коннект к серверу. Может кто знает в чем может быть проблема?
Код стандартный как на msdn. Вот код клиента

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "8379"

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0){
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("WSAStartup success\n");


    struct addrinfo *result = NULL, hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;


    iResult = getaddrinfo("93.74.72.231", DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0){
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("getaddrinfo success\n");

    SOCKET ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ConnectSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
        printf("Error at socket(): %i\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("socket() success\n");

    iResult = connect(ConnectSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR){
        closesocket(ConnectSocket);
        ConnectSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(result);

    if (ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
        printf("Unable to connect to server!\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("connect success\n");
// не весь код
}
```

Когда я делал в локальной сети и на одной машине в функцию getaddrinfo я передавал 192.168.1.108 и localhost соответственно. Теперь когда делаю в разных сетях, я передаю адрес сети в которой есть компьютер. Но что-то нужно еще добавить. Ведь в этой сети есть несколько компьютеров, а нужно подключится именно к компьютеру-серверу в этой сети. Но я не знаю что и куда добавлять.

Ниже код сервера.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEFAULT_BUFLEN 512
#define DEFAULT_PORT "8379"

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int iResult;

    iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("WSAStartup success\n");


    struct addrinfo *result = NULL, hints;

    ZeroMemory(&hints, sizeof (hints));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;


    iResult = getaddrinfo(NULL, DEFAULT_PORT, &hints, &result);
    if (iResult != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %d\n", iResult);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("getaddrinfo success\n");

    SOCKET ListenSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;
    ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

    if (ListenSocket == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("Error at socket(): %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("socket() success\n");


    iResult = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen);
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        printf("bind failed with error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        freeaddrinfo(result);
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(result);
    printf("bind success\n");


    if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR){
        printf("Listen failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("listen success\n");

    SOCKET ClientSocket;
    ClientSocket = INVALID_SOCKET;

    ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL);
    if (ClientSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
        printf("accept failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        closesocket(ListenSocket);
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }
    printf("accept success\n");
//не весь код
}
```

Comment: Ощущение, что вы не совсем корректно формулируете вопрос... Мне кажется (хотя я могу быть и неправ), что вы указываете ip роутера, за которым локалка 192.168.x.x? тогда на роутере должен быть настроен проброс порта на нужную машину и порт...

Comment: да, все верно. настроил проброс портов все работает.